# What is the macro CV_OCL_RUN used for in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I was learning [*hog.cpp*](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp) implemented in **OpenCV**, when encountered the macro [`CV_OCL_RUN`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/opencl/ocl_defs.hpp) and confused with it.

In [*hog.cpp*](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp) where [`detectMultiScale()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp#L2046) locates, you can find [`CV_OCL_RUN`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp#L2073) and a method called [`ocl_detectMultiScale()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp#L2004) in it. Compared between [`detectMultiScale()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp#L2046) and [`ocl_detectMultiScale()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp#L2004),  not only their names but their implement are quite similar.

Here are my questions:

1. What is the macro [`CV_OCL_RUN`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/opencl/ocl_defs.hpp) used for? Does it for test or other purpose?
2. Since [`detectMultiScale()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp#L2046) and [`ocl_detectMultiScale()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp#L2004) are so similar in functionality, why the later is embedded in the former ? What ways are they called in?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

1. `CV_OCL_RUN` is for [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) code.
2. If your computer is not able to use OpenCL capabilities (no GPU or no OpenCL driver), regular code (CPU) is run. You can also switch between regular code or use OpenCL version in the code. If [`setUseOptimized()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga3c8487ea4449e550bc39575ede094c7a) or [`setUseOpenCL()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dc/d83/group__core__opencl.html#gadb3b41d4552e9db7887855e3a1b2af37) is set to false, regular code will be used.

You can find in the [opencl](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/3.2.0/modules/objdetect/src/opencl) directory the kernel code which will be run on the GPU device.

PS: `OpenCL` is not only for GPU.

Comment: Thanks, I will find some reference on OpenCL